# Problem of Analysis about Matrix Exponential, Infimum and Limit

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \times \mathbb{Z}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(X,z) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} |x_i z|,
$$
where $x_i$ is the $i$-th row of $X$ and $x_iz$ is a dot product of $x_i$ and $z$.
My question is:
Is it true that
$$
\inf_{z \neq 0} \lim_{X \rightarrow 0} f(e^{X+C}, z) = \lim_{X \rightarrow 0} \inf_{z \neq 0} f(e^{X+C}, z) ?
$$
Some observations that I deduce about this:

1. $e^{X} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{X^{k}}{k!}$ is infinitely differentiable and therefore $e^{X+C}$ is continuous.
2. I think that you don´t need to know about the constant $C$, but $C = \log b$ and the definition is that $e^{C}=b$. $C$ is a matrix, i.e., $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.
3. Actually, still I believe that we don´t need to know about the function $f$ the same way that I wrote above. I think that the problem can be formulated as follows:

Given $f: \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \times \mathbb{Z}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, is it true that $\inf_{z \neq 0} \lim_{X \rightarrow 0} f(X, z) = \lim_{X \rightarrow 0} \inf_{z \neq 0} f(X, z)$?

So I can´t do how prove it. I tested with some examples in Matlab and Wolfram Mathematica and the equality has always been valid.

One of the ways which I thought was to "open" the expressions of both sides of equality and try to reach the same result. To reach the infimum, I thought that $z$ should have all coordinates equal to zero, except 1 coordinate. In this case, I have $z \neq 0$ and maybe this is a vector that works to prove it. But I didn´t get anywhere.

Comment: Maybe you want to put a title which is more informative.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, I´ll write more informative title now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generalized problem is not true. In the case $n=1$, let
$$f(x,z)=\begin{cases}-1 & \text{if }x\geq\frac{1}{|z|+1},\\-(|z|+1)x & \text{if }x\in[0,\frac{1}{|z|+1}).\end{cases}$$

This function is obviously continous with respect to $x$, but
$$0=\inf_{z\neq 0}f(0,z)=\inf_{z\neq 0}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x,z)\neq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\inf_{z\neq 0}f(x,z)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} -1=-1.$$

I'm uncertain about your original problem. After some consideration, I realize that my previous claim may not always hold.

Comment: Thanks. I don't check it, but I will give points for you help me. Thanks again